# Lumen QueryException When Running API

Tags: php, lumen

I'm learning about Lumen Framework and reading that tutorial: [Developing RESTful APIs with Lumen](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-lumen/)

Currently is working, but when i access my api

http://example.com/api/accounts/2

it returns

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'youframe.accounts' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `accounts` where
>   `accounts`.`id` = 2 limit 1)

I have a model file called Account.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Account extends Model
{
        protected $fillable = [
                'username', 'email', 'password', 'type' 
        ];

        protected $hidden = [];
}
```

and a controller file called AccountController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Account;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
        public function getAccount($id, Request $request)
        {
                $this->validate($request, [
                        'token' => 'required'           
                ]);

                return response()->json(Account::find($id), 400);
        }
}
```

i have no table called `accounts`. My only table is `account`, from where it's calling `accounts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add table name to your model to associate your model with backend DB table.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Account extends Model
{
        protected $fillable = [
                'username', 'email', 'password', 'type' 
        ];

        protected $hidden = [];
        protected $table = 'account';
}
```

If you don't mention the table name, Laravel will assume the plural form of your model name as the table name. For more reference, see [Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions).

**UPDATE**

if you want to select only certain columns, use select command in your eloquent query.

```
$rows = Account::select(['column_name_1','column_name_2'])->get();
```

OR if you want them in an array

```
$rows = Account::select(['column_name_1','column_name_2'])->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Living and Learning. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre Welcome :)

Comment: for example, if i need get just specific fields, how to do?

Comment: @MauroAlexandre Didn't get you. Can you give an example?

Comment: Currently the API it's giving all fields from table, how to get only specifics?

Comment: Nice. You help me a lot. I'll learn the doc before learn tutorials. Thanks again.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre Glad to help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179707/discussion-between-mauro-alexandre-and-vivek-23).